# Copy multiple columns of varying length to new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code which copies a column to a new `workbook`. I need to copy further columns from the same worksheet to the same destination. I cannot seem to find the best method to do this. Please help

I do have headers in each column. I want to copy:

- column `L` to Column `A` in new workbook
- column `M` to Column `B` in new workbook
- column `B` to Column `C` in new workbook
- column `C` to Column `D` in new workbook

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Details As Variant, mydata As Workbook

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
      Details = .Range(.Cells(4, "N"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp)).Value

    End With


    Set mydata = Workbooks.Open("C:\destination file")

    With mydata.Worksheets("template")
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(Details, 1), UBound(Details, 2)) = Details

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Why go into troubles to calculate the last row when you can copy *full* column?

Comment: I have headers in the source data which I don't want to move across, destination workbook also has headers which I want to keep

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim Source as workbook
 Dim SourceSheet as worksheet
 Set Source = Thisworkbook 'or as required
 Set sourcesheet = source.worksheets(1) 'or as required
 Dim Destination as Workbook
 Set Destination = Workbooks.OPen("C:\destination file") 'as required
 Dim DestSheet as Worksheet
 Set DestSheet = Destination.worksheets("Template") 'or as required
 Dim dest as range
 set dest = destsheet.range("a1")
 with sourcesheet
    .columns("L:M").copy dest
    set dest = dest.offset(0,2)
    .columns("B:C").copy dest
  end with
```

end sub

Comment: can't say I am a fan of your layout, and if this enforces good coding practice.

Comment: How would you lay it out?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to copy several ranges, I suggest you seperate the copy code into a parameterised Sub, and pass it the ranges to process.

Something like this. In this example, the number of columns to copy is determined from `FromRange`. `ToRange` needs only to be any cell in the destination left most column.

```
Sub CopyData(FromRange As Range, ToRange As Range)
    Dim Data As Variant

    With FromRange.Worksheet
        Data = .Range(FromRange, .Cells(.Rows.Count, FromRange.Column).End(xlUp)).Value
    End With
    With ToRange.Worksheet
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, ToRange.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)) = Data
    End With
End Sub
```

Use it like this

```
Sub DemoCopy()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim FromRange As Range, ToRange As Range

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\destination file")
    'Copy columns L and M starting row 4, to A and B starting at next available row
    CopyData ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("L4:M4"), wb.Worksheets("template").Range("A1")
    'Copy columns B and C starting row 4, to C and D starting at next available row
    CopyData ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B4:C4"), wb.Worksheets("template").Range("C1")
End Sub
```